# why i have the same error when i put button ,image,etc in the layout

Tags: android

Hardcoded string "TextView", should use @string resource  Hardcoding text 
attributes directly in layout files is bad for several reasons:  * When creating configuration variations (for example for landscape or portrait) you have to repeat the actual text (and keep it up to date when making changes)  * The application cannot be translated to other languages by just adding new translations for existing string resources.  There are quickfixes to automatically extract this hardcoded string into a resource lookup.  Issue id: HardcodedText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add those strings to the `strings.xml` under the `res` folder instead of hardcoding them in the XML. You can add the string like this in the strings.xml:

```
<string name="my_new_string">Here goes your text</string>
```

Then you can reference it like this in your XML:

```
android:text="@string/my_new_string"
```